# PHP: Find all Filenames in a String

Tags: php, pattern-matching, filenames

I have lots of strings with embedded filenames the like ('file' ist just an example for a filename)

```
$string1 = '?file.png#hello/file.pdf<____!.sss<>file.docx';
$string2 = '###file.txt#§§/FILE.png(((file.pdf**';
```

The filenames are valid Linux or Windows filenames.

I need to extract all filenames (without paths) into an array from  string, e.g.:

```
$first = string2filenames($string1);
// $first should be [ 'file.png','file.pdf','file.docx' ]

$seconnd = string2filenames($string1);
// $seconnd should be [ 'file.txt','FILE.png','file.pdf' ]
```

How to write the function string2filenames?

Tried already with preg_match_all (with pattern `'/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/'`) but didn't succeed.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/NesfXO/1 maybe not perfect but it's a start for you

Comment: Is the name always file or is that just coincidence?

Comment: @Andreas: this is just an example filename

Comment: Alright. If you know the extensions of file names you can narrow the search (and improve the pattern) with say "/(\w+\.[docx|xlsx|PDF])/" and so on. Or if you know it's only three and four letter extensions and file names are without dots "/(\w+\.\w{3,4})/"

Comment: @WeSee did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found something that may actually work.
Try it out and see.

It matches filenames with multiple dots and on your example strings and some more advanced it seems to hold up.
Click on preg_match_all and look at [0] (full match).
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/kK2

```
$pattern ="/([A-Za-z0-9 _-]+\.)+(\w{3,4})/";
```

Edit; \w did not capture _-